# How to I load branch lists from multiple repositories using the Git Parameter plugin?

Tags: git, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

The description of the Use Repository field is confusing.  It doesn't appear to be working the way I expect it to work but the description is written in confusing English.  Take a look at the attached images.

[image]
[image]

I explained my goal in the description of the first Git Parameter.  Essentially I need multiple Git parameters and each must pull the branches from a different repo.  Either all of the branches listed are from one repo or the other gives an error.  I'm 100% confident that the repo links are corrected because I copied those directly from other working Jenkins builds just to be sure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, this was supposed to be fixed in [JENKINS issue 45419](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45419) and [this diff](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin/compare/a7d90cf52948...5c009d9e6b89).

Said diff includes a [`testMultiRepositoryInOneSCM`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin/blob/ca6df8360a4bc271e34470a9b98d106a58ccfc98/src/test/java/net/uaznia/lukanus/hudson/plugins/gitparameter/GitParameterDefinitionTest.java#L854-L886) which uses `.*git-parameter-plugin.git` and `.*git-client-plugin.git`, and expects:

```
origin/master
origin1/master
```

Maybe using those regexes (instead of https://...) would work better.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that on Monday and reply back if it works.  It isn't clear to me from the description of that field how to use a regex.  I wish I could find more info about that somewhere.  Without a complete link I don't see how it could work.